# How to create resque workers in heroku properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have these Resque workers defined in my Procfile

```
resque1: env QUEUE=mailer rake resque:work
resque2: env QUEUE=calculation rake resque:work
```

But seems non of them gets created, is it because the process type is wrong? If yes, how can I create two resque workers for my rails app?

[Problem Solved]

The reason been heroku only give one free dyno and the rails app already used one. Once I scale the web dyno to 0, and scale my resque dyno to 1 instance, the queued job gets executed immediately.

Thanks!

Comment: paste result of `heroku ps`

Comment: Some how I can not have two dyno for free in Heroku.